# Crash while inserting int a set

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr, aerospike

My program seems to be crashing while inserting and int into a set, and I cannot track down the reason for this.  Here is there relevant code:

```
bool request::check_list(std::vector<int> search_vec)
{

    std::set<int> *tmp_ptr = create_int_set();
    boost::shared_ptr<std::set<int> > c_list(tmp_ptr);


    if(aerospike_query_foreach(as, &err, NULL, &query, process_set, &c_list) != AEROSPIKE_OK)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < search_vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if(c_list->find(search_vec[i]) != c_list->end())
        {
            c_list_value_ = search_vec[i];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;       
}

bool request::process_set(const as_val *val, void * udata)
{
    try
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<std::set<int> > c_set = *(boost::shared_ptr<std::set<int> > *)(udata);
        if(val == NULL)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(val->type == AS_REC)
        {
            if (val!=NULL)
            {
                as_record *rec = as_record_fromval(val);

                if (rec!=NULL)
                {
                    as_integer* c_id = as_record_get_integer(rec,"c_id");
                    int cid = 0;
                    cid = boost::lexical_cast<int>(c_id->value);
                    if(c_set != nullptr)
                    {
                        c_set->insert(c_id);
                    }
                    as_record_destroy(rec);
                    as_integer_destroy(c_id);
                }
        }
        return true;
    }catch(...){}
    return false;
}
```

The line `c_set->insert(c_id);` is causing a segfault.  Here is this backtrace of the crash:

```
#0  0x00007f2064299f94 in std::_Rb_tree_rotate_right(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007f206429a12b in std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00000000004829d9 in std::_Rb_tree<int, int, std::_Identity<int>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_<int const&> (this=0x7f1fcc005440, __x=0x0, __p=0x7f1f3c0009a0, __v=@0x7f20159e729c)
    at /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_tree.h:981
#3  0x000000000047f1e0 in std::_Rb_tree<int, int, std::_Identity<int>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_unique<int const&> (this=0x7f1fcc005440, __v=@0x7f20159e729c)
    at /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1299
#4  0x000000000047c473 in std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::insert (this=0x7f1fcc005440, __x=@0x7f20159e729c)
    at /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_set.h:415
#5  0x00000000004765ee in request::process_set (val=0x7f20159e73e0, udata=0x7f200b9d6620) at ../../request.cpp:1862
```

I am assuming there is a problem where the set is not being initialized, or something similar to that.  Here is how I create and pass the set from the another function, I have tried two ways to create it:

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::set<int> > c_list(new std::set<int>());
```

and

```
std::set<int> *tmp_ptr = create_int_set();
boost::shared_ptr<std::set<int> > c_list(tmp_ptr);

std::set<int>* request::create_int_set()
{
    return new std::set<int>();
}
```

The calling function is a callback function from a database driver, that takes in a few different objects, most notably however are the process_set and the c_list, which is passed as a void*:

```
aerospike_query_foreach(as, &err, NULL, &query, process_set, &c_list)
```

This crash does not happen all the time, in fact it is fairly rare, which makes me think there is something I am doing wrong, some sort of undefined behavior.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a lifetime issue. There's nothing we can do with these little isolated snippets, though. Where is your [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I will update in a minute with more of the flow, but there is not a whole lot more too it.  Hopefully the additional code will give you a better idea though.

Comment: The line casting a `void *` to a `shared_ptr *` sends shudders down my spine. I don't _know_ that it's wrong, but I'd suggest sending in `c_list.get()` to `aerospike_query_foreach` and use a raw `std::set<int>` pointer in the `process_set` function; it asserts no ownership/sharing does not appear to be threaded/reentrant, so it should be safe to do so.  (At least, try that to eliminate a reference-counting error…)

Comment: Lightness: Updated the OP to include the calling function.  Basically anytime I get a request, my program will call check_list, which checks to see if any value from the list is in the database.
Matthew:  I had a feeling it might be the shared_ptr, I'll give passing in the set a shot.

Comment: I dislike being ignored when I'm trying to help someone, Eumcoz. Make a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Lightness:  I'm sorry I won't be able to make a verifiable test case in this case.  As I said before I am not able to reproduce this problem easily, it is an intermittent problem.  I provided a minimal, complete example of my code.  The only way I can provide a verifiable solution is to provide you all of my source code, which will not be possible.

Comment: @Eumcoz: It's not minimal because half of the code obviously has nothing to do with the problem, e.g. the comments or the try/catch or the log output. It's likewise not complete because we cannot easily try to compile it on our own machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [aerospike APi documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/de/d96/group__query__operations.html#ga1daa1661dc5020e34749bd9aece7987b) says for the callback  (i.e. `process_set()`, here):

> Execute a query and call the callback function for each result item.
>   Multiple threads will likely be calling the callback in parallel.
>   Therefore, ***your callback implementation should be thread safe.***

As several threads might insert at the same time in the same set (the one pointed to by your shared pointer),  you'll get race conditions and hence undefined behaviour !

So I think that you should protect at least your set insertion block with a `lock_guard` on a mutex.

**Important edit:**  `boost::shared_ptr<>` [can't assumed to be thread safe](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety).  In the examples on boost.org, they suggest that a shared pointer going out of scope might cause a race.   It may therefore be highly advisable to follow  **[Matthew Moss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612003/matthew-moss)**'s suggestion in the comments and use a raw pointer to the set within the bounds of process_set().

Comment: Thank you Christophe,  that may be it, I will throw in a mutex around the insert and see if that fixes the problem, I should have checked the Aerospike documentation first.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I'd suggest a tool like ThreadSanitizer or valgrind to confirm the issue.

Comment: @Eumcoz Unfortunately, the mutex arround the insertion block might not be sufficient.  See the edit.

Comment: Thank you for the information, looking into structuring my code differently to use a mutex as well as using a raw pointer!